# How Can I Transform a Colored Image into Pre-defined Matrix?

Tags: image-processing, image

I am new to *Mathematica* and I would like to use it to postprocess some of the experimental data I measure.  I would like to visualize voltage measurements over a non-uniformly segmented plate. I would like to read in the segmentation in terms of a colored scheme.  The color scheme would define the segmentation in geometrical shapes. For instance, I would have a red rectangle, an orange triangle, a blue triangle and a green square.

From what I know, I can represent the colors in terms of a `Matrix` using the `ImageData[]` command. However, with this, I obtain a `3X1` matrix for each color.  I would like to know if there is a way to represent each color by one number.  I ask this since I would like to take the `Matrix` I obtain and correlate it to the matrix which identifies the segment numbers according to the segmentation as follows:

```
Red --> Segment 1 (Rectangle)

Orange --> Segment 2 (Triangle)

Blue --> Segment 3 (Triangle)

Green --> Segment 4 (Square)
```

Comment: A sample image would help.

Comment: You might look at `ColorQuantize` -- this will reduce the color space to a specified number of colors.

Comment: Although I tried to answer this, I now realize that I don't understand the question... Could you clarify: what data you have; how you want to transform it; and what you want the end result to consist of? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
i = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 60];
data = ImageData[i, DataReversed -> True];
getColor[{r_, c_}] := 
 Which[
  Mean[data[[r, c]]] < 0.1, Blue,
  Mean[data[[r, c]]] < 0.3, Green,
  Mean[data[[r, c]]] < 0.5, Red,
  Mean[data[[r, c]]] < 0.7, Orange,
  True, Pink]
getShape[{r_, c_}] :=
 Switch[
  getColor[{r, c}],
  Red, {Red, Rectangle[{c, r}, {c + .75, r + .75}]},
  Green, {Green, Rectangle[{c, r}, {c + .75, r + .75}]},
  Blue, {Blue, Polygon[{{c, r}, {c + .5, r + 1}, {c + 1, r}}]},
  Orange, {Orange, Polygon[{{c, r}, {c + .5, r + 1}, {c + 1, r}}]},
  Pink, {Pink, Rectangle[{c, r}, {c + .75, r + .75}]}
  ]
Graphics[
 Table[
  getShape[{row, column}],
  {row, 1, Length[data]}, 
  {column, 1, Length[data]}],
  Background -> Black,
 PlotRangePadding -> 0
 ]
```

[image: lena gone geometric]

I had trouble with my rows/columns/x/y... :)